# Replace old body element with new loaded element

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I am loading my page contents with ajax using .load()

My html pages are formatted the following way:

For my home page is:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body class="HOME">
    <header></header>
    <div id="content">
      //CONTENT
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

For my article pages is:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body class="ARTICLE">
    <header></header>
    <div id="content">
      //CONTENT
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am loading only the contents inside the div element with id `#content`. Now, let's say we go from the article page to the home page, at the moment, the body element keeps the old class `#HOME` What I want is to replace it with the new loaded body element that contains the class `#ARTICLE`

EDIT:

```
jQuery('.link').on("click", "a", function() {

 jQuery('body')
    .find("#content")
        .fadeOut(10, function() {

            jQuery('#content').hide('slow').load('/' + " #content", { is_ajaxed_page: "yes" }, function() {

                jQuery('#content').fadeIn(10, function() {

                });
            });
        });

    return false;
});
```

EDIT 2:
Partial solution. For now, I am setting the new class manually like this:
After the content has been loaded:

```
jQuery('body').attr('class') = 'HOME';
```

However, I want to retrieve the class of the new body automatically when loading the content. Something like this:

```
var newBodyClass = jQuery('body').load('/ body').attr('class');
jQuery('body').attr('class') = newBodyClass;
```

Comment: Please share your jQuery code.

Comment: @DerekS edited to add jQuery code.

Comment: If you're replacing the entire page, why bother using ajax?

Comment: Have you tried just changing the class name on the body?  `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className = 'MYNEWCLASS';`

Comment: @Kyle, I could do that but how do I get the new class from the loaded url?

Comment: @Jonathan because other parts of the site have ajax loading for certain elements. So in order to offer a consistent user experience, I want to have the homepage loaded with ajax as well.

Comment: Do that within the `.load` callback function.

Comment: @derek_duncan I did that, but it keeps returning the old class from the previous page instead of the new class from the loaded url.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you remove the previous code.

```
jQuery('.link').on("click", "a", function() {

 jQuery('body')
    .find("#content")
        .fadeOut(10, function() {

            jQuery('#content').hide('slow').empty().load('/' + " #content", { is_ajaxed_page: "yes" }, function() {

                jQuery('#content').fadeIn(10, function() {

                });
            });
        });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: What does `empty()` do in there? I just tried it, but it is still returning the old class.